# How to get more faster touch frequency for ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm programming a game in which as I touch the screen a ball follows my movement.
My touch code resembles this:

```
...
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
ballX = currentX;
ballY = currentY;
invalidate();
```

And naturally I handle the OnDraw event and drawing the Oval with drawOval.

As the application starts in the simulator all works as instructed but it seem that by increasing the velocity of the touch (mouse) the ball moves with a very high latency so that as I stop to move, I should wait up to 1 sec while the ball reaches the last position. Is there a way to increase the frequency of the ACTION_MOVE events to fire faster or to improve the overall behavior of this program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you're describing typically indicates that you're receiving the **ACTION_MOVE** events **faster** than you're handling them. This causes the events to be queued up and handled after you lift your finger. The source for your problem is, most probably, that the call to *invalidate()* takes a lot of time.

A possible solution to your problem can be to handle a **ACTION_MOVE** event once every N events:

```
int moveEvtCnt = 0;  
int N = 5; // Handle every 5 movement events  
..
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
if((moveEvtCnt % N) == 0) {
    ballX = currentX;
    ballY = currentY;
    invalidate();
}
moveEvtCnt++;
```

In the example above, you'll handle the **ACTION_MOVE** events every 5 samples. Since *invalidate()* is called less frequently it can better track your finger's motion in real-time, instead of wasting processing time on past, and irrelevant, events.

Comment: I tryed this..tryed also to invalidate only the really needed rect but the situation is almost the same..Only a little bit better. Do you know were to find a code sample for this particular situation ?